# what causes " inline method not to work for chrome browser"?

Tags: javascript, x3d, x3dom

I have uploaded a **3D** object in `.X3D` format using `inline method` in `X3DOM` frame work. Its loading well in **Mozilla Firefox** browser, but not in **Google Chrome**.

Can someone please let me know why it doesn't work and what things have to be done to make it even work on Google chrome?

Thanks.

Comment: try to use a debug console and see what happens when you load the page. Normally it should work. X3D is supported by Mozilla, Chrome an d Safari as far as I know

Comment: check this example in Google Chrome given by x3dom.org                   http://x3dom.org/x3dom/example/blenderExport/horse-inline.html

Answer (score 0):

You said "upload", but I had a problem debugging my html in local with chrome beacuse chrome doesnt get local files without "--allow-file-access-from-files" flag execution.